# Download latest artefact package from Jfrog artifactory in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, jfrog-xray

I have set of zip files that are in Artifact Repository and I need to get the latest artifact. The structure of the artefacts are as listed below

Homeloan 
   -> test-application-dev-local_1.zip 
   -> test-application-dev-local_2.zip 
   -> test-application-dev-local_3.zip 
   -> test-application-dev-local_4.zip 
   -> test-application-dev-local_5.zip 
   -> test-application-dev-local_6.zip 
   -> test-application-dev-local_7.zip

All these artefacts are an output of Msbuild. Everytime when the user checks-in their code it gets built in TeamCity and artefacts are uploaded to Jfrog.

Now I have a another TeamCity build which is triggered on adhoc basics which needs to get the latest artefact and in this case I need "test-application-dev-local_7.zip".

I'm using TeamcityArtifactory plugin to get artefacts and below is the spec I tried.

```
{
    "files": [{
        "aql": {
            "items.find": {
                "@build.name": "test-application-dev-local_*.zip"
            }
        },
        "target": "somepath",

    }]
}
```

With the above spec I get all the 7 zip files. I tried adding limit to the above spec(I'm not sure if this is the correct way) but I'm getting the error

```
{
"files": [{
    "aql": {
        "items.find": {
            "@build.name": "test-application-dev-local_*.zip"
        }
    },
    "limit":1
    "target": "somepath",

}]
```

}

```
Error occurred while resolving dependencies from the spec: Unrecognized field "limit" (class org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.spec.Aql), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "items.find"])
```

I'm not sure how to retrieve the artefacts that was uploaded recently.

Comment: you can use teamcity artifact dependency.

Comment: Thanks @SeniorPomidor. I'm currently using teamcity artifact dependency to get the latest or last build artifact. But I want to avoid the artifact dependency as the requirements for me is to get the latest artifact from JFROG.

Comment: did you figure this out ?

Comment: @devcodes no, currently using some workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was stuck at this , as the Artifactory [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+File+Specs#UsingFileSpecs-DownloadSpecSchema) says -

> "Currently sortBy, sortOrder, limit and offset are not supported in
> TeamCity."

So had to look around for any other way to implement these . What worked for me  ?

->

I was able to do so by [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory) command .

Had to recreate the spec file on command line and for sort and limit purpose , used the CLI command instead of adding sort and limit in the spec file .

```
echo ">>> Downloading the archive from artifactory ..."
echo "{" > downloadSpec.json
echo "  \"files\": [" >>downloadSpec.json
echo "    {" >> downloadSpec.json
echo "      \"pattern\": \"artifactory-repo-path/artifact-name*.tar.gz\"," >> downloadSpec.json
echo "      \"target\": \"target-path\-to-download"" >> downloadSpec.json
echo "    }" >> downloadSpec.json
echo "  ]" >> downloadSpec.json
echo "}" >> downloadSpec.json


jfrog rt dl --spec=downloadSpec.json
--url="your-artifactory-server-url" --user="your-artifactory-user-name" -- 
password="your-artifactory-password" --sort-by=updated --sort-order=desc 
--limit=1
```

where `jfrog rt dl` -> is the command to download